# what wrong with SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error

Tags: macos, vapor

```swift
let param = uploadObject
do {
    return try req.make(Client.self)
        .post("https://up-z2.quiniup.com", 
            headers: HTTPHeaders([("ContentType","multipart/form-data")]),
            beforeSend: { (post) in
                try post.content.encode(param)
        })
} catch {
    throw Abort(.internServerError, reason: "Unable to upload file to quiniu.com.
        Underlying error \(error)")
}
```

I want to upload file via third party API. Call it in a request I get an error:

> SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=20, pid=12915

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?